# ts-node and mocha 'TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"' error even with "ts-node/esm" loader and CommonJS modules

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

Before ask this question, I checked similar topics and tried typical solutions.

I know what the frequent cause is `"module": "ESXXXX"` in TypeScript configuration.
In my case, I have error

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for D:\IntelliJ IDEA\XXXXXX\node_modules\tsconfig-paths\src\__tests__\config-loader.test.ts
```

in both `"module": "ESnext"` and `"module": "CommonJS"` cases.

One of typical solution is usage of **ts-node/esm**.
First, this feature is experimental. Next, it just replace one error with another:

```
(node:24788) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

× ERROR: CustomError: Cannot find module 'D:\IntelliJ IDEA\XXXXX\node_modules\tsconfig-paths\register' imported from D:\IntelliJ IDEA\XXXXX\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js
```

### Versions

- mocha: 9.2.1
- ts-node: 10.7.0

### Mocha config

```
extension:
  - ts

spec: "**/*.test.ts"

require:

  - ts-node/register
  - tsconfig-paths/register

loader: ts-node/esm # Tried with and without
```

Comment: I'm working on this same issue. Looks like the issue here: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1279

Comment: @CraigFisher, Thank you for listening of the voice of us, Mocha users. Would you please to write the cause in answer? I'll give you the reputation points.

Comment: What a nightmare. I was getting this because had one new package that was ESM, but the test run wasn't telling me that was the cause at all. I was only getting this really generic error. So also check if you have any only ESM modules. If you can avoid them, I guess do so as it's a whole world of hurt.

Answer (score 24):

i'm using same configuration like yours but it only work when i downgrade to ts-node@9,
and then i tried this option in my `.mocharc.json` and now it's working as i expected

```
{
  "extensions": ["ts"],
  "spec": ["**/*.spec.*"],
  "node-option": [
    "experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
    "loader=ts-node/esm"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Downgrading ts-node to @9 helped me as well, even despite I have a different setup: `mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register tests/startup.ts tests/**/*.test.ts`. It's absolutely strange since I have a few repositories, and in one of them `ts-node@10` went fine. Might be a dependency clash. In this repo where I needed `@9`, I'm using typia.io for dynamic types validation.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error and it worked for me to set the `NODE_OPTIONS` env var to specify the loader:

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--loader ts-node/esm" mocha
```

Taken from here: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/imports#native-ecmascript-modules

It might also help to upgrade to the latest version of ts-node 10.8.0

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. More info: https://github.com/nicolo-ribaudo/jest-light-runner/pull/50

Comment: For me, this just triggers an additional error: `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension "" `

Comment: Why not put that option in a mocharc file as @martiendt recommends? wfm

Answer (score 8):

Do you have a `tsconfig.json`. That solution could help here:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/piotrwitek/ts-mocha/issues/70#issuecomment-1055978592) is an interesting thread about it with an alternative solution. In that case, the `tsconfig` has an include that looks like this:

```json
"include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
]
```

One of these two options should work, but let me know. Not sure what your config looks like.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but `"esModuleInterop": true` did not help (I had this option initially). Also tried `"include": [ "Source/**/*" ]`.

Comment: Can you post your config and your import statements?

Comment: for what did this answer gain the bounty, if it was not the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 8):

This absolutely misleading error with `mocha`/`ts-node` may happen in case any of your dependencies are ES6 modules (!), but your TypeScript target is not. For instance, when having a package `got@13.0.0` installed:

```
✗ npm run test      

> @mypackage@1.6.0 test
> mocha -r ts-node/register tests/**/*.test.ts


TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /.../tests/index.test.ts
...
```

And now downgrading to `npm i got@11`, which still provides CommonJS exports:

```
npm run test

> @mypackage@1.6.0 test
> mocha -r ts-node/register tests/**/*.test.ts

// All right
```

So a "quick fix" for this annoying error might be to downgrade a certain package you have just upgraded (typically, a major version). This is related to `got`, `node-fetch`, and other packages that decide to publish ES6 only code.

Otherwise, you have to update your entire test suite. I don't know any "ultimate" fix for the `mocha`+`ts-node` setup for this problem. Some other test suites like `vitest` or `playwright` work well with ES6 deps out of the box, and in some projects I personally started to use "transpile-then-test" approach rather than testing directly on TypeScript sources with runtime `ts-node`.

Comment: This was quite useful. I actually had to travel back 4 major versions on `serialize-error` to find one, that did work. Then the vNext of this NPM stated, that ESM was required. Enabling ESM however, causes many other new errors for me. While I am still stuck, you provided enough "more" context to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find a work-around for the issue in the end? I have this exact same issue but would preferably apply the new major version rather than sticking to v4 of chai

Comment: Hi @Daniel! As I explain in the post, I moved my repos to a transpile-then-test approach, where you don't need `ts-node/register` at runtime.

For instance, in my setup in most service-level repos on TypeScript, I use `"build": "tsc && tsc-alias"` in package.json, which outputs the "build" directory, which includes both `.js` files and transpiled `.test.js` files (most of my repos have related tests next to source files). Then, you don't need any `ts-node/register` or whatever to run your tests, just use `"test": "mocha ./build/**/*.test.js"` and it will run all tests in the build directory.

Answer (score 4):

I added "type": "module" in package.json and did `npx tsx file.ts` instead of using `ts-node file.ts` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late to the party, but I just upgraded my Chai assertion library to an ESM only package and ran into this issue. The problem occurred for me when my typescript files imported Chai. ts-node would rewrite those typescript files to use `require('chai')` which would throw the error described in this question. For Chai specifically I was able to globally require chai in my mocharc file and then remove the problematic imports from my test files written in typescript.

.mocharc.json Now looks like this for me with "chai/register-expect.js" added to the require array. They have other register-*.js files for should and expect too.

```json
{
  "extension": ["js", "ts"],
  "spec": "test/**/*",
  "require": ["chai/register-expect.js", "ts-node/register"]
}
`
```

Comment: I updated a bunch of dependencies and I thought that mocha or ts-node upgrades were the reason my mocha tests were complaining that ".ts" extension is unknown. However, upgrading libs one-by-one showed the place where everything breaks - chai update from 4.3.6 to 5.0.0. Since I'm not an expert neither in js nor in npm, I just left the library at the old version... if you have more details and context, I would gladly follow your instructions and update chai.

Comment: Typescript/javascript world is such a mess, I have no idea what means ESM or commonjs modules, their compatibility and the whole history behind.

Answer (score 2):

May be it is too late a bit, but may be help someone:

For me the cause was "too new" url-join depenendency.

So this can happen even if your `package.json` do not have `type: "module"` or such, but you have a dependency with `type` set to `module` as `url-join` latest, here error goes.

Mentioned here: https://github.com/piotrwitek/ts-mocha/issues/70#issuecomment-1027582584

Answer (score 1):

**ts-node/register**
would do the trick.

Node developers: Add this to your `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {"test": "mocha --parallel -r ts-node/register /path/to/test.ts"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `package.json` is set to `"type": "module"` try the following (taken from https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/issues/47)

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
    }
}
```

**.mocharc.json**

```json
{
    "node-option": [
        "experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
        "loader=ts-node/esm"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its quite late but get rid of `ts-node` use `tsx`

- Install `tsx`, put it in dev dependencies
- you can remove `ts-node` from package file
- modify your test script to

```
  "test": "mocha --timeout 10000 --import=tsx src/__tests__/**/*.test.ts --exit",
```

Note: we are getting rid of `ts-node`

- Under is tsconfig changes

```
    "target": "ES2020", 
    "module": "commonjs"
```

Note: I am using node `v20.11.1`