# How to deal with "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error in Node.js + TypeORM seeding case?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, seeding, ts-node, node.js-typeorm

I got the error

> [cause]: Error: Unable to open file: "D:\IntelliJ IDEA***\TypeORM_DataSource.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module

error when tried to run the seeders by

```bash
typeorm-seeding \
  --dataSource 01-Source/Implementation/Elements/DataBase/TypeORM_DataSource.ts \
  seed 01-Source/Implementation/Elements/DataBase/Seeders/*.ts
```

using [@jorgebodega/typeorm-seeding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jorgebodega/typeorm-seeding).

Well, it is the frequent error with **ts-node**, but each time the cause thus the solution are different. In my case, the adding of `"type": "module"` to `package.json` does not solve the problem.

By the way, the TypeORM migrations works fine:

```
typeorm-ts-node-esm migration:generate ./01-Source/Implementation/Elements/DataBase/Migrations/Initialization -d ./01-Source/Implementation/Elements/DataBase/TypeORM_DataSource.ts
```

### Train of thought about cause

In the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jorgebodega/typeorm-seeding), the example with `.ts` has been gave:

```bash
typeorm-seeding seed -d path/to/datasource src/seeders/*.ts
```

Thus, **typeorm-seeding** must have the build-in TypeScript support.
Most likely, it is using the **ts-node**.

The usage of `export`/`imports` keywords is completely basic scenario for the TypeScript.
Into what it will be transpiled - the different question.
Should not the **typeorm-seeding** care about transpiling of the input TypeScript to appropriate types of modules?

### Appendix

#### TypeScript configuration

Theoretically, the `ts-node` settings should solve the issues with modules type.

```json
{

  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    "baseUrl": "./01-Source",
    "paths": {
      "@CommonSolution/*": [ "./CommonSolution/*"],
      /* ... */
    }
  },

  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    },
    "require": [
      "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ]
  }

}
```

#### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Local-Database
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"

    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  # ...

volumes:
  DatabaseData:
    name: Example-Local-DatabaseData
    driver: local
```

Comment: Can you please try running it with https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx instead of ts-node and check if it does solve the problem

Comment: Why does your `ts-node` uses `"module": "CommonJS"`?

Comment: @Dimava, because ts-node has the limited ES modules support. In the past, the adding of `"module": "CommonJS"` was the solution of the same error!

Comment: @Dimava I just have recalled for what  `"module": "CommonJS"` was required. For the running of Mocha tests written by TypeScript. Maybe it is not required anymore, but it was [another big issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71378840/4818123).

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    },
    "require": [
      "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ]
  }
```

while the thing `"type": "module"` in `package.json` does is switching node *from* the commonjs modules to esnext, so you are now trying to import CommonJS module as ESNext which may causes the error

Try to remove it for `"module": "CommonJS"` from ts-node compilerOptions

---

I recommend trying https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx as a more modern and stable alternative to ts-node. It "just works" in most of cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but neither removing of `"module": "CommonJS"` nor adding of  `"type": "module"` have solved the problem. "I recommend trying tsx" - thank you for the recommendation but I current problem is the `typeorm-seeding` command.

Comment: Also, if set `type: module` in the "package.json", the error will change to `Unknown file extension ".ts"`.